# Call an array element before its declared

Tags: php, arrays

Sorry for this question but I just curious with this case. Okay for example I have an array elements :

```
<?php

     $data = array(
        'key1' => 'val1',
        'key2' => 'val2',
        'key3' => $data['key2'] //the point
     );

?>
```

I know it will get an error because I called an element whereas an array has not declared yet. But is it possible to do that? The fact, value for `'key2'` is dynamically.

Comment: Call something that doesn't exist until you define it? Good luck with that

Comment: Assignments work on right to left. Such as `$a = $a + 5`, `$a+5` is calculated then assigned to `$a`, so if `$data` doesn't even exist, you can't call `$data['key2']`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, but you can easily do this:

```
$data = [
    "key1"=>"val1",
    "key2"=>"val2"
];
$data["key3"] = $data["key2"];
```

Or even `$data["key3"] = &$data["key2"];` to link them by reference.

Comment: Whichever one fits your situation.

Comment: @SamuelCook You claimed my code is not syntactically correct. What's wrong with it?

Comment: it appears it is a `version` issue. I did not realize that as of 5.4 you could create (in my mind) square bracket arrays. Apologizes, I retract my previous statement.

Answer (score 1):

PHP processes that in this order:

1. Create the array with its initialized values.
2. Assign the array to variable $data.

So no, you can't do it in one line. Of course, you can assign 'val2' to a variable, then assign to both keys.